# executing a code in a string

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, eval

I have a string by the name code in a meteor javascript file A which contains an export statement.

```
"export function hello() {
    //content of the function
}"
```

I need to import hello to file B which is another meteor javascript file.

I tried including

eval(code)

in file A. But its not working. Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more info.

Comment: somethings like this? https://jsfiddle.net/s6nzLpg5/

Comment: 'eval' is not good in your case, or is it not just working?

Comment: `eval` is pretty dangerous, could you maybe explain what you’re trying to do – there might be a safer way.

Comment: I'm using a package which formats a code snippet. The package returns the formated code in the form of a string which is of the format ' export default function(){ ------ } '. I need a way to access the function in the string.

Comment: Got it. I extracted the code portion of the function to a string. Let the string be code . The function can be created as follows let hello = Function(args, code); Now hello is the required function with arguments args.